# Unit-speed parametrization of $\langle t^2, t^3 \rangle$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vector-analysis

I need to do a change of variables ($t$ to $s$) for $r(t) = \langle t^2, t^3 \rangle$ such that the speed along the curve is always $1$. My trouble is in varifying that $||r'(s)|| = 1$.

$$ s(t) = \int_a^t ||r'(u)|| du = \int_a^t \sqrt{4u^2 + 9u^4} du = \int_a^t u \sqrt{(4 + 9u^2)} du$$

Letting $x = 4 + 9u^2$ then

$$\frac{1}{18}\int_{4 + 9a^2}^{4 + 9t^2} \sqrt{x} dx$$

$$ s(t) = \frac{1}{27}[(4 + 9t^2)^{3/2} - (4 + 9a^2)^{3/2}] $$

We can write $||r'(t)||$ as $\sqrt{t^2 (4 + 9t^2)}$ and from the previous equation we have

$$ 4+9t^2 = [27s + (4+9a^2)^{3/2}]^{2/3} $$

and

$$ t^2 = \frac{[27s + (4+9a^2)^{3/2}]^{2/3} - 4}{9} $$

So plugging these into $\sqrt{t^2 (4 + 9t^2)}$ gives me $||r'(s)||$ but I don't see how it reduces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not verify that $\|r'(s)\|$ is one. What you verify is that the curve $\gamma(s)=r(t(s))$ has speed one w.r.t. the new time parameter $s$. Just write
$$
s(t)=\int_a^t\|r'(u)\|\,du
$$
so that $\frac{ds}{dt}=\|r'(t)\|$ and therefore $\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{1}{\|r'(t(s))\|}\,.$ Then we have trivially by the chain rule
$$
\gamma'(s)=\frac{d}{ds}r(t(s))=\frac{d}{dt}r(t(s))\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{r'(t(s))}{\|r'(t(s))\|}
$$
which has norm one.

Comment: Oh I see. The way I was verifying it missed the chain rule.

Comment: And $a$ can be anything as long $|| r'(t)|| $ isn't zero everywhere?

Comment: $a$ can be anything. The only condition we need is that $\|r'(t)\|$ is *nowhere* zero.

Comment: But my book says "If we assume that $||r′(t)||= 0$ for all $t$, then $s(t)$ is an increasing function of $t$. In this case, $s(t)$ has an inverse, which we denote $t = \phi(s)$..." It doesn't use that fact that it is nowehere $0$.

Comment: You and I defined $s(t)$ in exactly the same way. The book is obviously wrong or has a typo. A total no brainer.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. Should say $|| r'(t) || \neq 0$ for all $t$. Still, it's a weaker assumption than you are making.

Comment: In my first comment I made the assumption that $\|r'(t)\|$ is *nowhere* zero, in other words, *not zero for every* $t\,.$ Why is your assumption weaker ?

Comment: It's weaker because 'nowhere $0$ $\implies$ isn't $0$ everywhere' but 'isn't $0$ everywhere $\not\!\!\!\implies$ nowhere $0$'. I understand that your assumption is sufficient, I'm just pointing out that my book says it's not necessary. We can asume the weaker 'isn't $0$ everywhere' and still get the result.

Comment: Last attempt: Claim:  $f(t)\not=0\,\,\forall t\Leftrightarrow \{f=0\}=\emptyset$ ($f$ is nowhere zero). Proof. Assume $f(t)\not=0\,\,\forall t$ and that $\{f=0\}\not=\emptyset\,.$ Then there exists a $t$ such that $f(t)=0$. A contradiction. Conversely assume $\{f=0\}=\emptyset$ and that there exists a $t$ such that $f(t)=0$. Also a contradiction. Nothing is weaker.$\Box$